# The ComplexData plugin does not exist, after upgrade

Tags: upgrading

After my Drupal 8.51 upgrade, I keep getting this error.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "ComplexData" plugin does not exist."

I have Googled it for two days and haven't found any information about what this is or how to fix it. I get the error while using Panels/Page Manager. I did upgrade both modules to the 4/14 release but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the cache?

Comment: Yes, I have. And also updated modules and done database update

Comment: How did you upgrade? Using composer or drush?

Comment: I upgraded with Composer. I am also noticing that I am getting this whenever I try to add a new taxonomy term, in addition to when I am working with pages and variants. Very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

I read in another post where an OP wrote that Composer didn't put all the /core files in place, so he manually copied the /core directory and all its files and that solved a similar problem he was facing.

I tried that last night, manually copying the Drupal 8.51 /core folder into my local install. It fixed the problem. I then copied the files into production and all is well. Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: `Composer didn't put all the /core files` something seems wrong here..

Comment: Agreed. I'm now looking at that.

Comment: If you are running OSX/Linux, ensure you have the latest version of Composer, as well as `patch`. With Homebrew on OSX, you can get the latest version with `brew install gpatch`. Not sure of the Linux equivalent but probably similar. Mine is currently `GNU patch 2.7.6`. Late last year I had issues with the newer version of Git and some issue with patch that I needed to update.